Unity - NullReferenceException - UniversalAdditionalCameraData
estoy trabajando en un proyecto XR en unity y estoy teniendo un incoveniente, en el editor constantemente me salta este error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.UniversalAdditionalCameraData.get_cameraStack () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@14.0.11/Runtime/UniversalAdditionalCameraData.cs:441)
OVRProjectSetupRenderingTasks+<>c.<.cctor>b__4_62 (UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal.UniversalAdditionalCameraData cameraData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.meta.xr.sdk.core@68.0.3/Editor/OVRProjectSetup/Tasks/Implementations/OVRProjectSetupRenderingTasks.cs:573)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) (at <a314714511a14f84b853c03efd8682b8>:0)
OVRProjectSetupRenderingTasks+<>c.<.cctor>b__4_47 (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup buildTargetGroup) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.meta.xr.sdk.core@68.0.3/Editor/OVRProjectSetup/Tasks/Implementations/OVRProjectSetupRenderingTasks.cs:570)
OVRConfigurationTask.UpdateAndGetStateChanged (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup buildTargetGroup) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.meta.xr.sdk.core@68.0.3/Editor/OVRProjectSetup/Tasks/OVRConfigurationTask.cs:189)
OVRConfigurationTaskUpdater.ProcessTask (OVRConfigurationTask task) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.meta.xr.sdk.core@68.0.3/Editor/OVRProjectSetup/Tasks/Processors/OVRConfigurationTaskUpdater.cs:59)
OVRConfigurationTaskProcessor.Update () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.meta.xr.sdk.core@68.0.3/Editor/OVRProjectSetup/Tasks/Processors/OVRConfigurationTaskProcessor.cs:107)
OVRConfigurationTaskProcessorQueue.Update () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.meta.xr.sdk.core@68.0.3/Editor/OVRProjectSetup/Tasks/Processors/OVRConfigurationTaskProcessorQueue.cs:132)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at <e0a2c8363ef54a6393fed120beebdb7a>:0)


como les digo sale constantemente durante el editor, incluso si no se esta corriendo el juego. No tenia problema con el porque pese a ser un error me dejaba poner play y jugar, el problema aparecio cuando queriendo compilar para probarlo en el casco Oculus Quest 3, el programa directamente no me debaja hacer Buil and Run, y me salta el mismo error.
En mi proyecto solo tengo las camaras que me dan en el paquete Meta XR all in one.
